# Windows phone webdriver (selenium community)/ Nunit silverlight framework of windows for Windows phone unit test?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, selenium

I am new to Windows phone and Remote webdriver. I want to automate windows phone app/ unit test windows phone app. I have worked on Robotium and I am also getting advice on Nunit framework for this project. Does Nunit framework is better compared to selenium webdriver? Which one I should go with considering all parameters?

Comment: a web app/site running through mobile browser on Windows phone 7/8/8.1? Or actual native/phone app on Windows phone 7/8/8.1?

Comment: There should be no difference to compare between NUnit and Selenium Webdriver. You can combine use of both - run Selenium WebDriver code/commands within an NUnit test. Or you can use Microsoft's test framework over NUnit as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look at **[Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps)** framework. 
It enables to automate Windows Phone applications.

- [Test examples & documentation](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps/wiki)